# Why is Mule DataWeave output to flowVar converted to string?

Tags: mule, dataweave

Is there any specific reason why output of Transform Message to flowVars or outboundProperties is converted to String but in case of payload it stays as WeaveOutputHandler ?

[image]

Screenshot from Mule Debugger with payload and flowVars.myVar generated with the same DataWeave script:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    request: {
        id: 100
    }
}
```

Problem with this is that you can't use flowVars.myVar.request.id in any further transformations in your flow.

Comment: Are you trying to access it later using MEL or in another dataweave transform?

Comment: In another dataweave transform

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a Tranformer Object to XML after the first Transform Message.

If this doesn't work, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

String is the correct type for XML data. It sounds like you want it converted to a Java object graph.

Change the %output to applicaton/java this will map the data to a hashmap based java graph that in most cases should work for the access method you are using.

Comment: Lol just realised, you asked this 2.5 years ago -